# Column pivot problem getting repeated Id with pivot columns having null values

Tags: sql-server, group-by, pivot

At the top the result of my pivot and below is the original table

[image]

I want a result like this
    AssetId | 77 |    78     | 79   |    80    |     81    | 82
    1571539 | 99 |01/01/2020 | L460 | Avast Pro| 01/30/2020| NULL
    8323444 | 103|01/28/2020 |PhoneI| Avast Pro| Null      | NULL

```
@pAssetTypeId int
as

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TBL_TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TBL_TEMP

DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @AssetId AS Varchar(MAX)

SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(fm.FieldMaintenanceId)
FROM dbo.FieldData f
   LEFT JOIN dbo.AssetType a
   ON f.AssetTypeId = a.AssetTypeId
LEFT JOIN dbo.FieldMaintenance fm
   ON f.FieldMaintenanceId = fm.FieldMaintenanceId
   where a.AssetTypeId = @pAssetTypeId

SET   @SQLQuery =
   N'SELECT AssetId,' +   @PivotColumns + '
   INTO #TBL_TEMP
   FROM [dbo].[AssetDetails] a
   PIVOT( MAX([Data])
   FOR [FieldMaintenanceId] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) as Q'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

Select * from #TBL_TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click to see desired pivot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sClY8.png)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TBL_TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##TBL_TEMP

DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @AssetId AS Varchar(MAX)

SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + 
QUOTENAME(fm.FieldMaintenanceId)
FROM CONCEPASSET.dbo.FieldData f
   LEFT JOIN CONCEPASSET.dbo.AssetType a
   ON f.AssetTypeId = a.AssetTypeId
   LEFT JOIN CONCEPASSET.dbo.FieldMaintenance fm
   ON f.FieldMaintenanceId = fm.FieldMaintenanceId
   where a.AssetTypeId = 3
```

SET   @SQLQuery =
       N'Select * 
       from 
       (
       Select 
         AssetId,
         AssetTypeId,
         FieldMaintenanceId,
         [Data]
       from AssetDetails )  AS SourceTable PIVOT(MAX([Data]) FOR [FieldMaintenanceId] 
       IN('+@PivotColumns+')) AS TableTest  '

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Reworked the code and it worked thank you all!!